# WiFi antenna understanding, which is 2.4, 5 GHz

Tags: antenna, wifi

My USB WiFi adapter has two antenna connectors, I have a lack of knowledge of these connectors, few questinos:

- how to check which connector is 2.4/5 GHz or both are 2.4/5 GHz at the same time?
- comes with [these two antena](https://77hobby.pl/images/produkty/FRSANT5DB_01.jpg), as I see its a 2.4 GHz antenna, then why vendor gives me two 2.4 GHz antennas without 5 GHz antenna?
- I could connect to one connector 2.4 GHz antenna and to the second connector 5 GHz antenna?

Comment: Can we have the specs for the USB WiFi adapter? There is no useful context here...

Comment: for example [this one](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/1.htm)

Comment: Both antennas do both frequencies.

Comment: Since 5 GHz is 2 x 2.5 GHz, a 2.5 GHz antenna can work well enough on **both** frequency bands.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Actually 2.4 and 5.8 GHz for [802.11ac](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/connectivity/wifi-ieee-802-11/802-11ac.php), not exactly an harmonic, and the antennas probably don't work in λ/4 or  λ/2.

Comment: @mins Then please enlighten me why many dual band laptops and routers share the same antennas for both bands. I wrote that they work **well enough**. Even if an antenna isn't \$\lambda/2\$ or \$\lambda/4\$ it doesn't mean it does **not work**. It works but just isn't optimal.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: I didn't say it doesn't work, I just commented on your statement "5 GHz is 2 x 2.5 GHz" (2:1)  which is a shortcut as actual values are 2.4 and 5.8 GHz (2.4:1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The USB Wifi adapter you mentioned has two antennas. Each of these operates on both 2.4 and 5GHz bands per the specification-"2.4G/5GHz Dual-Band 5dBi dipole antenna".

The reason you have 2 antennas is to enable the MIMO/beamforming/multiple concurrent transmissions capabilities as defined by 802.11ac

Comment: Useful links: [MIMO](http://www.multicap.be/en/technology/mimo-and-spatial-streams) and [beam steering / forming](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/80211ac-a-survival/9781449357702/ch04.html)

Answer (score 3):

In antenna deisgn, you have something called standing wavelengths where you have a zero crossing at each wavelength. 2.4Ghz is close to 2.5 or half of 5Ghz and an antenna can be tuned to operate at both frequencies. There are many antennas though that can't do both so I'd look at the datasheet to make sure. From what you showed that antenna should be able to work on both 2.4 and 5 GHz channels, do you have two different connectors that are labeled 2.5 and 5Ghz?

Comment: there is some [disassembled pictures](https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-market-ugc/1540738/2a000001689c3acc6db026499715978b830d/700-700), connectors are not labeled as 2.5 or 5Ghz

Comment: [Here is](https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/251.htm) alfa 2.4 GHz antenna. Specs: `Frequency` 2400 ~ 2500MHz, then this can be tunned to operate on 5 GHz?

Comment: @TheAnotherWise why don't you pick one of the antennas explicitly spec'ed as dual-band? https://www.alfa.com.tw/products_detail/136.htm for example?